# Check if this is an instance of new google.maps.LatLng in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have my JS object.

```
function Foo() { 
    this.bar = new google.maps.LatLng(12, 34);
}
```

I did also a getter and setter:

```
Foo.prototype.SetBar = function(bar_arg) {
    this.bar = bar_arg;
}
```

and

```
Foo.prototype.GetBar = function() {
    return this.bar;
};
```

How to force user to provide only `google.maps.LatLng` object as `bar_arg`?

In other words, if user will call `this.setBar('i am a string')` instead of `this.setBar(new google.maps.LatLng(56, 78))` I would like to throw an exception to do a specific action. Is **[instalceof](http://www.herongyang.com/JavaScript/Prototype-instanceof-Operator-Determine-Object-Type.html)** a good idea? If it is then how should I check?

`if ( ! bar_arg instanceof google.maps.LatLng) { //throw new... }`

or just

`if ( ! bar_arg instanceof LatLng) { //throw new... }`

*Obviously Google Maps API is loaded.*

Comment: How do you deal with the [LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-latlng-literal?hl=en) which Google Maps API now accepts, i.e. a simple Javascript structure like `{lat: 12, lng: 34}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track with `instanceof`.

In fact, a slight modification of your attempt:

```
if (!(bar_arg instanceof google.maps.LatLng)) { //throw new... }
```

Should be exactly what you need...

Comment: It seems that you're wrong. It's weird because `not` operator doesn't work in this case. If I will remove `!` and add `} else { //there i can throw }` then it throws exception in the `else`.

Comment: Then you may need to add `()`, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yes! That did work. Thank you. Sorry, I'm tired today.